# import sklearn not working in PyCharm

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pycharm

I installed numpy, scipy and scikit-learn using pip on mac os. However in PyCharm, all imports work except when i try importing sklearn. I tried doing it in the Python shell and it worked fine. Any ideas as to what is causing this? 
Also, not sure if it is relevant, but i installed scikit-learn last.

The error I receive is unresolved reference

Comment: What errors are you getting when you try to import sklearn?

Comment: hi, I'm getting the "unresolved reference" error

Answer (score 6):

I managed to figure it out, i had to go to the project interpreter and change the python distribution as it had defaulted the OS installed Python rather than my own installed distribution.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

In my PyCharm Community Edition 5.0.4, Preference -> Project Interpreter ->  check whether sklearn package is installed for the current project interpreter, if not, install it.

Answer (score 2):

**PyCharm January 2020 Build**

- Click on **File-> Settings**
- From the **Settings Dialog-> Projects-> Your Project**
- Click on (+) on right side and type search for **sklearn**
- Install it and you are good to go

[image]

**If you are behind a proxy then first set proxy to AutoDetect**

[image]